# Validation of @RequestParam in Spring REST controller doesn't work

Tags: spring, validation, spring-restcontroller

I want to validete my GET method's params. I added tis dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I wrote this controller:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@Validated
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public String getTest(@Min(value = 3, message = "min 3")
                          @RequestParam("hz") String hz,
                          @RequestParam("hz1") String hz1) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I added configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor;

@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

the request works fine! Why?

```
http://localhost:8088/test?hz=12&hz1=123
```

Comment: You can make the validation inside your service, it's more suitable

Comment: No, the more logic we dump inside services the more it becomes error prone, while simple validation logic if discarded from controller itself, we will have clean and minimal code in service layer!

Comment: can you please show error ?

Comment: @ silentsudo which error? My question was about no error. I expected any validation error. I think I solved this problem and I will add an answer later